# array element order change from another array element value using map()

Tags: javascript

set array element from another array element value

i have two array. array pqr objects set on array xyz's value using map()  method and another method.

pqr array order change on xyz array element value like as getting output section array using map() function and after more simplicity like as afer section array.

```
input: 
var pqr = [{name: 'R', age: '20'},
            {name: 'S', age: '30'},
            {name: 'R', age: '18'}]

var xyz = [3, 1, 2]

output:

            [{name: 'S', age: '30'},
            {name: 'R', age: '18'},
            {name: 'R', age: '20'}]

after:

[{'S': '30'}, {'R': '18'}, {'R': '20'}]
```

Comment: how is `xyz` related to the result? is that the wanted order of the int value of `age / 10`? maybe yoiu choose some more meaningful variable names. what is the the meaning of *after*?

Comment: What is your question?  Where is your attempt at solving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const pqr = [
  { name: "R", age: "20" },
  { name: "S", age: "30" },
  { name: "R", age: "18" }
];

const xyz = [3, 1, 2];

const sorted = pqr.slice().sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age);

const according = xyz.map(position => sorted[position - 1]);

const result = according.map(item => ({ [item.name]: item.age }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: how do you know that OP use `sort` ?

Comment: @Kamil Kiełczewski I suggested it basing on example

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski If I understood OP correctly, they are asking to reorder `pqr` using the array of indexes provided in `xyz`

Answer (score 0):

```
var k = [{name: 'R', age: '20'},
        {name: 'S', age: '30'},
        {name: 'R', age: '18'}]

var l = [3, 1, 2]

var e = l.map( info => {
    var w = k[info - 1];
    if(w.name == 'S'){
        w.age = '25'
    }
    return ({[w.name]: w.age});
})
console.log("ee", e);
```